# how to Send email without postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

### form_code.aspx.cs

When I click button send CodeRandom to Email page will refresh and modal missing.

I need page without postback when i click button

```
char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789".ToCharArray();
        Random r = new Random();
        string randomString = "";
        string Code;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            randomString += letters[r.Next(0, 35)].ToString().Trim();
        }

        Code = "Code : " + randomString;

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("-----@gmail.com");//from
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txt_email.Text.ToString().Trim()));//
        msg.Subject = "Verify Email by SnaBlack";//ชื่อsubject
        msg.Body = Code.ToString().Trim();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("------@gmail.com", "------------");//password
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Use update panel..!!

Comment: We do this  on our application by an email.asmx (web service) and ajax to call it.

Comment: Ok thank you It's Work @rajeeshmenoth;  @Bindrid;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable PostBack in asp.net code

```
<asp:button runat="server" ... OnClientClick="return false" />
```

or js:

```
<input type="button" id"sendMail" onclick="callSendMail();return false;"/>
```

Then you can call your method from js via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: mailSendUrl,
    data: param = "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a request to the server via `AJAX` technologies. Use JS code on a `client side` (your actual generated HTML page) and request handler on a `server side` (.NET web service) using one of this technologies: asp.net web api, wcf, web methods (asp.net web forms), asmx (obsolete). Please, read more about it, because simple copy paste wouldn't help in your practice. Clear understanding of client-server interaction will help you easily build another samples without SO